# Questions concerning smallest fraction between two given fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, fractions

I recently encountered this on a practice test

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there exists an integer $m$ satisfying $0.33 < \frac{m}{n} < \frac{1}{3}$

My answer:

> $$\begin{align}0.33 < \frac{m}{n} < \frac{1}{3}&\implies(\frac{33}{100} < \frac{m}{n})\land(\frac{m}{n}<\frac{1}{3}) \\ &\implies(33n<100m)\land(3m<n) \\\end{align}$$ and thus $n=3m+1$.
>
> So $$\begin{align}33n<100m&\implies33(3m+1)<100m \\ &\implies 99m+33<100m\\ &\implies m>33\end{align}$$
> Taking $m\geq34$, we find that $n=34\times3+1=103$

After the test, I had the following thoughts, which I do not know how to answer.

**Questions**

Will the solution for $n$ always yield the smallest $m$ possible?

Does this method (find minimum value of $n$ and substitute) work for all such problems? (where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$)

Can we generalise $n$ for all possible fraction ranges, and if so, will $n$ always be of a certain form compared to $a,b,c,$ and $d$? (where $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{m}{n}<\frac{c}{d}$).

---

note: sorry for asking multiple questions in one post (which I know some people frown on) but I feel posting multiple questions with the same 'introduction' (problem+proof) would clutter and be somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: In my opinion the smallest is $n=103$ because the smallest $m$ is $34$. 
Indeed if you solve for positive $n$
$$\frac{34}{n}<\frac{1}{3}$$ you get $n>102$

Comment: @mathlove typo by me, thanks. I've also noticed that in our example $\frac{33}{100}<\frac{34}{103}<\frac{1}{3}$, the numerator of the middle fraction is the sum of the other numerators, and the denominator for the middle fraction is the sum of the other denominators. I wonder if this is a coincidence or not, though I won't put that into the question (three questions in one post is already plenty)

Comment: The [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for $\frac13$ is $(0;3)=(0;3,\infty)$ and the continued fraction for $0.33$ is $(0;3,33)$. The simplest between them is $(0;3,34)=\frac{34}{103}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can we generalise $n$ for all possible fraction ranges, and if so, will $n$ always be of a certain form compared to $a,b,c,$ and $d$? (where $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{m}{n}<\frac{c}{d}$).

This answer uses your method.

In the following, $a,b,c,d,m,n$ are positive integers.

$\frac ab\lt \frac mn\lt \frac cd$ is equivalent to
$$na\lt mb\qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{md}{c}\lt n$$

From the second inequality, we can set $n=\lfloor\frac{md}{c}\rfloor+1$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

So, from the first inequality, we get
$$\left(\left\lfloor\frac{md}{c}\right\rfloor+1\right)a\lt mb\tag1$$

As a result, we can say that the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there exists an integer $m$ satisfying $\frac ab\lt\frac mn\lt\frac cd$ is given by$$\left\lfloor\frac{Md}{c}\right\rfloor+1$$
where $M$ is the smallest integer $m$ satisfying $(1)$.

---

If $c=1$, then the smallest positive integer $n$ such that there exists an integer $m$ satisfying $\frac ab\lt\frac mn\lt\frac 1d$ is given by$$\left(\left\lfloor\frac{a}{b-da}\right\rfloor+1\right)d+1$$

Comment: Hello. Since $M$ depends on $n$, it doesn't seem obvious to me at all that "we can set $n=\lfloor\frac{md}{c}\rfloor+1$". For instance, it's imaginable that if you set $n_2 = \lfloor\frac{md}{c}\rfloor+2$, you could get a corresponding $M_2$ smaller than $M$, so that $n_2 < n$.

Comment: @Stef : I thought your comment was helpful, so I tried to add some explanations, but I realized it is obvious that $M\le M_2$ holds. I think you can see why.

Comment: Indeed I can see it now!

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both of your questions. This is essentially the [mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)) for two terms in a [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence). There is some deep theory here. Read up on Farey sequences for more information.

Comment: I had three questions - i'm assuming you're talking about the first two? either way, thanks for the links.

Comment: The mediant is not always the smallest. Take for instance $\frac13$ and $\frac34$: the mediant is $\frac47$, which is between the two, but $\frac12$ is the fraction with the smallest denominator.

Comment: I think the mediant is only relevant when the fractions are consecutive terms in some Farey sequence. In the example @robjohn gives, $1/3$ and $3/4$ are not consecutive terms in any Farey sequence.

Comment: You can iterate the algorithm using the mediant. For 1/3, 3/4 we get 4/7 and then with 1/3, 4/7 we get 1/2.